# How to run SQL on Local Host?

Tags: mysql, hadoop, virtual-machine, cloudera, cloudera-cdh

I've been trying to connect to MySQL on my Cloudera VM but I'm unable to connect to the server. I'm guessing the problem is because the terminal is on 'cloudera@quickstart'. The video which I am referring to has the terminal at 'cloudera@localhost'.
[The following error shows up when I try to connect to the MySQL server on my main OS from my Cloudera VM ;](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BbOfj.png)

[This is how the terminal shows for the video I'm referring to;](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JvR1n.png)

If anyone could please help me run the terminal '@localhost', it should solve the problem, I hope. Any help is appreciated, as I'm unable to find any solution to this. Thanks!

Comment: try not to use blank password

Comment: @Frost - I tried that. The same issue comes.